# Al seleccionar una opción de un select de html me habilita el teclado del móvil/celular

Tags: html, css

Resulta que tengo un select en un programa que estoy realizando en codeigniter, al desplegar este select me habilita el teclado en el celular o móvil, en la versión de pc no hay problema, pero en la versión de celular al desplegarse el teclado no me deja seleccionar nada.

Estoy utilizando la biblioteca select2.

Espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer es un bug del componente, puedes verlo en su pagina de [github](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1541), en el hilo te aparecen algunas "ñapas" para que funcione mientras lo solucionan, como añadir la opcion `minimumResultsForSearch:-1` al componente, pero al parecer no funciona para todos los navegadores, te recomiendo que le eches un ojo al hilo para ver si encuentras algo mientras solucionan el bug.